# Restore master database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, restore, master-system-database

I want to restore my `master` database (.dba ).

I am not able to restore from PowerShell because the backup of the database is taken from a different version of the SQL Server and the PowerShell or `cmd` method does not allow it.

I moved to T-SQL, but now problem is T-SQL is not starting in single user mode.

How to run T-SQL in single user mode? Or is there another way to restore the `master` database?

I am using SSMS 2014.

Comment: use  -m; (don’t forget the semicolon and don’t leave any space) Use this article: http://www.travisgan.com/2012/08/restore-master-database-in-single-user.html

Answer (score 1):

It isn't powershell itself that restricts you, it is SQL Server which doesn't allow restoring master from a different version. And the reason why you don't get in with SSMS is that SSMS opens several connections and only one connection is allowed with -m. So use SQLCMD.EXE to try the restore instead, but you will see that you will get the same error as you got from powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You have to shutdown sql server and start it in single user mode (in configuration manager, you specify `-m` as start up parameter) and then restore master database. See : this [mssql tip for more details](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3266/restoring-the-sql-server-master-database-even-without-a-backup/).

Comment: not working,  already set `-m `. when restart service first time it connects. but when upload file it fails, reason:server is in single user mode.

Comment: can you post what you are trying including the restore command ? Also, what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

After restarting your SQL Server, do not open SSMS.

Follow a simple restore command via sqlcmd and you should be able to restore it. If your SQL Server version is same for the master database and installed SQL Server. See a quick tutorial [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/14/sql-server-restore-master-database-an-easy-solution/).